# Loading multiple files from folder to power bi dashboard

Tags: powerbi

I have a situation:

I'm trying to load multiple files from a folder with the .txt format. It turns out that I can filter the individually loaded files so that they don't refresh when updating the information that's already loaded and only add files that are not already there. The issue is that I'm currently using folder-based loading, and it brings in all the .txt files I have.

Please keep in mind that ultimately, this will be automated, so no one should have to perform this task manually.

I need to optimize the loading process so that only new files are refreshed, and the previous data remains intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the load from folder or file based solutions. It will always load the whole folder and not just the changes. You can do it using a database as a data source, so load the files in a database, then used incremental loading in PBI. This would use a defined date column to load the latest data inserted into the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think I got what I was looking for!

Comment: It would be nice if you share the solution you found.

Comment: @Raky The answer is the solution, the answer was accepted . It can't be done on the file level, its needs a database

Comment: @jon, I had unrelated `.xlsx` files which i wanted to load into `Power BI` as individidual tables, akin to manual import of 1 file at a time. I was unable to do. After lots of research, I could achieve it by first loading all `.xlsx` files into a `.xlsm` using a VBA Macro. Thereafter, I imported the `.xlsm` queries into `Power BI`. I wish **Microsoft** provides to import multiple excel files directly and Also provides Macros in Power BI.